# _Pragma("GCC error") is processed differently inside and outside a #if directive

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, pragma

I'm experiencing a behavior that I find weird with the preprocessing of `_Pragma("GCC error")`.

I get the same results with avr-gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 and with gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4).

The source code:

```
#define E               _Pragma("GCC error \"This is an error\"")

#define _IS_VOID_       , 1

/*  Return "1" if <c> is "", return "0" otherwise.
 */
#define ISVOID(c)         _ISVOID2(c)
#define _ISVOID2(c)       _ISVOID3(_IS_VOID_##c,0,)
#define _ISVOID3(...)     _ISVOID4(__VA_ARGS__)
#define _ISVOID4(v,x,...) x


"ISVOID(something):" ISVOID(something)
"ISVOID():" ISVOID()
"ISVOID(E):" ISVOID(E)


#if ISVOID(something) == 1
"ISVOID(something)==1: true"
#else
"ISVOID(something)==1: false"
#endif

#if ISVOID() == 1
"ISVOID()==1: true"
#else
"ISVOID()==1: false"
#endif

#if ISVOID(E) == 1
"ISVOID(E)==1: true"
#else
"ISVOID(E)==1: false"
#endif
```

I process this with `gcc -E -std=c1x -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic main.c >output`.

I get this on the command line (almost normal):

```
main.c:16:11: error: This is an error
 "ISVOID(E):" ISVOID(E)
           ^
```

and this in the output:

```
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.c"
# 14 "main.c"
"ISVOID(something):" 0
"ISVOID():" 1
"ISVOID(E):"
# 16 "main.c"

# 16 "main.c"
 1





"ISVOID(something)==1: false"



"ISVOID()==1: true"







"ISVOID(E)==1: false"
```

Then, `ISVOID(E)` expands to `1` outside the `#if` directive and it expands to `0` inside, meaning that `_Pragma("GCC error")` is processed differently inside and outside a `#if` directive.

Moreover, there is no emission of a "This is an error" related to the `#if ISVOID(E) == 1`.

Is that behavior normal?

Comment: Interesting; mind-blowing — why is it a problem in practice?  When you preprocess, do you get a message like ```cpp13.c:15:11: error: This is an error``` and
```"ISVOID(E):" ISVOID(E)``` is identified as the location of the error?  Running cpp from GCC 6.3.0 on a Mac (macOS Sierra 10.12.3), that is part of the output, written to standard error, of course.  The preprocessor reports failure, of course (exit status 1).

Comment: This is a problem in practice for my [HWA project](http://github.com/duparq). This is a set of macros that gives an access to the hardware through a generic interface. I need to detect and handle errors (mostly typos) to emit polite and informative messages about the origin of the errors instead of the tons messages the compiler will throw about errors in macro expansions. As the user can use the HWA definitions both in source and in directives, I need the _Pragma to be process the same way whatever the context.

Comment: I also have the `cpp13.c:15:11: error: This is an error` located at `"ISVOID(E):" ISVOID(E)`.

I have the same result with avr-cpp (GCC) 4.9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC Bugzilla has confirmed that this is a bug (http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79948).